# Google Spreadsheets complex look up

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have three columns like so:

Column 1 is a numeric identifier essentially just the row number

Column 2 is a country name

Column 3 is a comma separate string of country ids, may be blank (represents a relation between the country for that row and the other countries in the comma separated list).

What I want is to put a comma separated list of countries in column 4 which is more readable than the ids.  Pretty much a code table look up but complicated because it is not a single value in the cell but a collection of values.  I don't own the table so I can't change the way the data is coming to me from the source - I can do whatever I want with it once I get it though :)

I could also live with breaking out the comma separate values into separate columns, so long as the new columns contain the country names and not the ids.

As requested here is a link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LY_8xh992pjZnoNSP-7P5x2iD1VVFozy8stlH4DLqNQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B,SEARCH(","&$A$2:$A&",",","&C2&",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for not posting a link to a spreadsheet - made you work harder than I should've :(